# react is not getting the css file correctly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

i'm trying to toggle the class "open" on my hamburguer icon, but it's not working as I imagined, I don't know why, the hamburguer icon will only appear on small screens, because of responsiveness

BELOW IS THE JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
import "./header.css";
import { useState } from "react";

function Header() {
  /*
  let menu = document.querySelector(".navbar ul");
  let hamburguer = document.querySelector(".hamburguer");
  hamburguer.addEventListener("click", function () {
    menu.classList.toggle("open");
  });*/
  const [hamState, setHamState] = useState(false);

  function abrirMenu() {
    console.log("click");
    setHamState((hamState) => !hamState);
  }
  let openMenu = hamState ? "open" : "";
  return (
    /*
    <head>
        <meta charSet="UTF-8" />
        <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
        <link
          rel="preconnect"
          href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"
          crossOrigin="anonymous"
        />
        <link
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <script
          src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c442a23036.js"
          crossOrigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <title>All Black design</title>
      </head>
      */
    <div>
      <header>
        <div className="menu">
          <div className={`navbar ${openMenu}`}>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#recuperacao">É difícil ser programador?</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#sobre">Se torne um programador</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#depoimentos">Veja o que diz quem já fez</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <input type="checkbox" id="hamburguer" />
          <label htmlFor="hamburguer">
            <div className="hamburguer" onClick={abrirMenu}></div>
          </label>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

BELOW IS THE CSS CODE

```
.container {
  padding: 0 2%;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1280px;
}
.menu {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 11px 0 10px 0;
  display: flex;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.navbar {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.navbar ul {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.navbar li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 0 60px;
}
.navbar li a {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(105, 1, 190);
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.navbar li a:hover {
  color: rgb(140, 0, 255);
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
.hamburguer {
  display: none;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hamburguer::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 70%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 20px;
  top: 30%;
  left: 15%;
  transition: 1s ease;
}
.hamburguer::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 20px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 35%;
  transition: 1s ease;
}
#hamburguer:checked ~ label .hamburguer::after {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
  top: 45%;
  background-color: white;
}
#hamburguer:checked ~ label .hamburguer::before {
  transform: rotate(-225deg);
  left: 15%;
  width: 70%;
  top: 45%;
  background-color: white;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1080px) {
  .logo {
    width: 40%;
  }
  .navbar ul {
    position: fixed;
    top: 100px;
    right: 0;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: red;
    /*background-color: rgb(121, 4, 217);*/
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in;
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  .open {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  .navbar ul li {
    padding: 15px 0;
  }
  .navbar ul li a {
    color: white;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in;
  }
  .navbar ul li a:hover {
    color: white;
  }
  .hamburguer {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

I used the useState on react to try change the class on the hamburguer element, but didn't worked out

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review the guidelines for [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what makes a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It would be very helpful if you could edit the question so your code would reproduce your issue if others copy and paste it into their own IDEs, and additionally you should describe explicitly what error messages you're seeing and where. Right now this question needs more details and clarity before it can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to it:

```
let openMenu = hamState ? "open" : "";
```

change it to

```
let openMenu = useMemo(() => {
    return hamState ? "open" : ""
  }, [hamState])
```

(then you need import useMemo)